How can I detect cursor hover location on 2 stacked up widgets in Flutter
Currently, I am trying to work on a project that requires me to pass cursor hover behavior from the top stacked widget to its lower widget. While also performing operations needed on that widget itself. This is my current attempt on it:
        Stack(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: MouseRegion(
                onHover: (event) {
                  debugPrint('Red: ${event.position}');
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 300,
                  width: 300,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: MouseRegion(
                hitTestBehavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                onHover: (event) {
                  debugPrint('Green: ${event.position}');
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 200,
                  width: 200,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )

Here, on hovering over the green container, the debugPrint statement of red container, does not get invoked.

You can use single MouseRegion on top of Stack and use localPosition to detect the hovered item

@Md.YeasinSheikh Nice solution. But unfortunately, I cannot do that. I can only perform operations for each widget, only when the cursor is above them specifically.

It turned out it is quite easy for the MouseRegion widget specifically.
We can simply set the opaque property to false, like this:
Stack(
    children: [
    Center(
        child: MouseRegion(
        onHover: (event) {
            debugPrint('Red: ${event.position}');
        },
        child: Container(
            height: 300,
            width: 300,
            color: Colors.red,
        ),
        ),
    ),
    Center(
        child: MouseRegion(
        opaque: false, //This will let all the mouse events also passed on.
        onHover: (event) {
            debugPrint('Green: ${event.position}');
        },
        child: Container(
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            color: Colors.green,
        ),
        ),
    ),
    ],
)


hover will only works on top widget even if you stack 10 widgets each above, first or top widget only get hover effect.
ex:- if you stack 10 papers each above and then you want to touch last paper from above you could never touch it that's how stack works.
so above widget can get hover effect and for lower widget you have to keep them aside to get hover fuctionality. that's the solution.

Bro, for my project I need to operate, based on the cursor position, on both of my widgets, stacked on each other. The Requirements cannot be changed. Our job is to find the solution.

yes i understand you requirement but in my case it is not possible, you answered that set  opaque false to first widget can't get hovered and now you get second widget hovered but what about first widget's hover effect this will not work in my opinion.
please correct me if i am wrong.

For me, when I set opaque property to false. It was printing both "green" and "red" print statements simultaneously.

it means that opaue allows to focus on first widget and on stacked widgets also that's great.
